# Javascript : make request again when accessing previous state

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I use this in my JS:

```
window.history.replaceState({url: , scrollTop: wTop}, 'foo', 'bar');
```

But when I go to another page from here then press the back button, I end up not firing a request. Instead, my browser loads everything back from its "disk cache". I'd like to fire the request again, since my state has change and it should ask for the corrected page.
How can I achieve that?

I tried with this in my rails controller:

```
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
```

But apparently, the history list is not entirely related to the cache feature.

Comment: Do you use Turbolinks? Is the Javascript you posted somewhere embedded in the document Body?

Comment: No I don't use Turbolinks. But the JS is indeed embedded into the body.

Comment: Mmmmh, correction : my JS is precomplied into one file that is inside the document Head, so no it's not in the Body in fact.

Comment: JS Definitive guide "when the user navigates to saved history states using the Back or Forward buttons, the browser fires a popstate event on the Window object. The event object associated with the event has a property named state, which contains **a copy of the state object** you passed to pushState()". I am guessing this is precisely the state you may get back to when browsing the history. You probably can change the logic by hooking into the popstate event - using the location.reload.method() for instance to reload the page. Just some thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it with a hidden input and a bit of script.  Something like the following assuming you have jQuery available (obviously just modify it if you're not using it):

```
<input type="hidden" id="reload_page" value="false" />
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if ($("#reload_page").val() == "true") {
       location.reload(true);
   } else {
       $("#reload_page").val("true");
   }
}
```

The "true" flag in the location.reload event tells it to reload the page from the server instead of from the cache.  The browser should store your input value as part of the cache, so the page will refresh when you return to it, but not when it first loads.

If you're working with a page that has been added instead, so that it has no historical state, you can reverse the process a little -- instead of a direct reload, as in the above, add a form to submit rather than a direct reload, something like the following:

```
<form id="reload_form" method="get">
<input type="hidden" id="no_refresh" val="true" />
</form>
```

Paired with a similar bit of script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!$.urlParam('no_refresh')) {
        $("#reload_form").submit();
    }
});
```

This makes use of the $.urlParam function found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/url-parameters-jquery/), but works on a similar principle to the natural "back" function in the snippet above -- once the form is submitted to refresh the page, the parameter becomes available, and the changed state prevents the script from refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [pop state listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate).

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
   alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};
```

If you don't add this listener, then the browser will behave in the traditional fashion, requesting the page from the server (or loading from cache) when the state changes.

NOTE: The browser caching header can still be used with push/pop state which improves first page loading.